# How to implement the Bubbles using Google Map API Application in asp.net C#

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

Google Map Api Application can be implement the Asp.net in C# applications.UI Forms only show on the City state and ZipCode Fileds only. i have search the City fields.can be display on the specific city location with in marker.

Answer (score 0):

javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

//Generate Markers Value Array
    var markers = [
    
    
                {
                "title":'<%# Eval("City") %>',
                "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
                "lng": '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>',
                "description": '<%# Eval("Name") %>
<%# Eval("Address") %><%# Eval("City") %>
<%# Eval("State") %> 
<%# Eval("ZipCode") %>'
              }
    
    
        ,
    
    
    ];
    
    
        window.onload = function () {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                zoom: 11,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

```
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        for (i = 1; i <= markers.length; i++) {
            var letter = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + i - 1);
            var data = markers[i - 1]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title,
                icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + letter + ".png"
            });

            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
    }
</script>
```

CodeBehind:
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblErrorMessage.Visible = false;
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                try
                {
                    DataTable dt = this.GetData("select * from utb_GoogleMaps");
                    rptMarkers.DataSource = dt;
                    rptMarkers.DataBind();
                    BindGoogleMapAPIData();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    showMessage(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Multiple Marker Show on GoogleMap method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="query"></param>
    ///// <returns></returns>
    private DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        try
        {
            string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;

                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);

                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```